# Update An Attribute in A Model (Table) Depending on the Previous Value of the Attribute Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have an attribute `amount` in some model `Stock`. If I want to set all the value of amount to 10 for all the rows, I will simply run:

```
Stock.objects.update(amount=10)
```

However, I want to update all the amounts in such way that 1 is added to all the amounts.
So, something like this:

```
Stock.objects.update(amount=amount + 1)
```

which is not possible, off course. But, I need something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do it like:

```
from django.db.models import F
Stock.objects.update(amount=F('amount') + 1)
```

Comment: What for string type fields? Should `F` work for string type too?

Comment: I haven't tested this but all it should do is find the old value 'amount' add 1 and update the object. Hows your 'amount' field stored? Int? or Char?

Comment: It's an Int, but I needed such thing for a Char field also.

Comment: @MuhammadMuaaz best idea is to just give it a go - its only a simple line of code :)

Answer (score 0):

stocks=Stock.objects.all()
for stock in stocks:
stock.amount=stock.amount+1
stock.save()